# POS thermal printer arabic letters separate printing issue

Tags: android, thermal-printer

I have a thermal printer attached with an epos device. I am developing an Android application in java that requires full receipt print for customers.
 I am fully able to print receipt but facing issue while printing arabic text. I am using windows-1256 encoding to print arabic letters. But letters that are printing is separated.
 Means ".  قيمت واحد". Is printing as ".  ق ي م ت و ا ح د".  .
My code for arabic print is

```
String print2 = "قيمت ؤاحد" ;
byte[] bytes23 = EncodingUtils.getBytes(print2,"windows-1256");
 outputStream.write(bytes23);
```

**This code only print arabic if android system language is set to arabic too**
Please help me out I am in need.

Comment: hey @Farah Abbas. Can you please give me the manufacturer and model of this POS printing device you're talking about? I'm looking over the internet for such a device

Comment: Please share email

Comment: Actually in market you can have many pos printers who prints arabic . Epson model is one of them widely used.

Comment: abdullah.bakhach@gmail.com

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I prepared Custom class for joining words. 
Basic Information:
Arabic has 6 letters that dont join to left.
Words like la ,alif lam needs to be taken care of.

Comment: Can you post your code to solve this issue? I am facing the same

Answer (score 0):

i fix it with

this

you can check it

this repo use 3 laiblary

secreenshot to convert widget to image
and image library to convert it to uint8
and pos_print to print it as u love to show

https://github.com/blackangiliq/flutter_pos_printer_spport_arabic